# How to view all mail in my exchange server

Tags: exchange-2003

How do i find the copys of all emails on my exchange server i have Exchange system manager 6.5 on windows server 2003 sorry i dont no what other details you will need to me provide

Comment: Wow. As I see you're from London, you do realise that there are several privacy concerns around this kind of behaviour don't you?

Comment: im not selling the data and i can do what i want im my own company as long as the data is safe

Comment: Ok. You keep believing that. You're wrong - you absolutely can't "do what (you) want" with email from other people just because you're the boss - but your mistakes are not my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Exmerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=429163ec-dcdf-47dc-96da-1c12d67327d5&displaylang=en) can be used to export all messages on an Exchange system to a PST file.

Comment: sorry but i want to view it all on the server without extracting it. i just cant remember what i did last time it was a few years ago

Comment: Define "view". As in, see all the messages on all the mailboxes in a single Outlook window?

Comment: as in list all mail and if i want to check out the contents of the email i can double click to open it. there must be an archive of some sort from all the mail that has been recieved/sent

Comment: There isn't, unless you have all your mail forwarded to a journal account.

Comment: There's no way to view the messages without extracting it with Exmerge or a third party tool.  You're stuck.

Comment: @ben950 The "archive" you speak of is the transaction logs, which would be purged/ overwritten after being backed up/ committed. If you specify more details about what this is for, there may be more helpful answers.

Comment: so say for example someobyd in my company has been sending off job applications during working hours and deletes from his sent items. how acn i go on the server to retrieve these emails

Comment: If they're not retained in his deleted items, they will no longer be in the Exchange server's database. You can use the Message Tracking Center (System Manager -> Tools) to see the subject line and headers, but that's about it. Restoring from a backup and/or checking for a Journal account is about all you can do.

Comment: @Hyppy, actually it will be in the Exchange servers database, in the dumpster portion of the DB, as long as the deleted items retention period hasn't been exceeded (server side).  Software is available that can extract these messages.

Comment: Thank you for all your help i would tick the answers but i dont have enough rep

Comment: @Holocryptic That's what I meant to say, retained in the dumpster. Sorry.

Comment: No worries.  I figured I'd mention it in case you didn't know (or forgot) :-)

Answer (score 2):

For real-time access,without opening each users mailbox via OWA or Outlook, or granting yourself access to their mailbox and opening it as an additional one in Outlook under your account, there is no way to do this.

Otherwise you will need to export the mail and open the .pst files.

What are you trying to do? Is this for an audit?

Comment: i wanted to moniter a few emails send from one of my users without loggin into there system and opening outlook

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to recover deleted items, you can use software like [Ontrack](http://www.krollontrack.com/information-management/email-management-for-exchange/) or [Mailretriever](http://www.appassure.com/applications/recover-emails/).  Barring that, there is other software out there that monitors and journals all incoming and outgoing mail like [Barracuda](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/archiver-overview.php) (although that's a hardware appliance).